# Bootstrap vertically push to the bottom

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="movies" class="well">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="well text-center">
        <img src="#">
        <h5>title</h5>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Detail</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="well text-center">
        <img src="#">
        <h5>title</h5>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Detail</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#movies img, #movie img{
  width: 100%;
}
@media(min-width:960px){
  #movies .col-md-3 .well{
    height: 390px;
  }
  #movies .col-md-3 img{
    height: 240px;
  }
}
```

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nyji.png) As you can see in the image, the Detail buttons are not in the same horizontal line. I would like to push the first one down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox` to achieve this. Try this (View it in "full page" mode).

```css
#movies img, #movie img {
  width: 100%;
}

@media(min-width:960px) {
  #movies .col-md-3 .well {
    height: 350px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  #movies .col-md-3 img {
    height: 240px;
  }
  #movies .btn {
    margin-top: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div id="movies" class="row well">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="well text-center">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/260">
        <h5>Qui minim nulla veniam.</h5>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Detail</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="well text-center">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/260">
        <h5>Ut reprehenderit cillum occaecat sint voluptate</h5>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Detail</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```